# Access data attribute of html element

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code but i cannot access the data-alt-engine attributen can someone please tell me where I am going wrong, thank you in advance!

```
<select id="HotelList" name="HotelList" style="visibility: hidden; height: 30px;">
 <option class="selectmsg" value="All" data-cluster="my hotel">SELECT HOTEL</option
<option class="hotel" data-cluster="france" data-alt-engine="">Hotel 1</option>
<option class="hotel" value="10216" data-cluster="france" data-alt-engine="1">Hotel 2</option>
</select>
```

jquery

```
   $("#HotelList").change(function () {
                   // alert("Handler for .change() called.");
                    if ($("#HotelList option").attr("data-alt-engine") == "1")
                    { alert("1"); }
                    else 
                    { alert("0"); }

                });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`attr` gets the attribute value from the **first** element that matches the selector.

The first option doesn't have a `data-alt-engine` attribute.

Possibly you want to get [the `:selected`](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) option element.

(Aside: You might prefer [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to `attr`))

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to access `data-*` attribute of the selected option which can be done using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method like:

```
$('#HotelList').on('change', function(e) {
   var $selected = $("option:selected", this);
   var altEngine = $selected.data('alt-engine') || '';
   if (altEngine == "1") {
      alert("1");
   } else {
      alert("0");
   }
});
```